# get mouse position on full screen java image with matlab

Tags: java, swing, matlab, mouseevent, fullscreen

It seems there not to be a method to show an image full screen with Matlab on Win8 64. So I found a solution somewhere using a java class, that is javax.swing.JFrame. I don't know java and more I cannot use Matlab command on java full screen image. My goal is to get the mouse cursor position on that image. Here is my code:

```
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent.*; %I tried also java.awt.event.* without results
import java.awt.Robot; %It doesn't seems to be useful

img=imread("my_image.tif");
jimg = im2java(img);
frame = javax.swing.JFrame;

mouse=java.awt.event.MouseEvent;  %here it doesn't work, the same if mouse=java.awt.event; 

frame.setUndecorated(true);
icon = javax.swing.ImageIcon(jimg);
label = javax.swing.JLabel(icon);
frame.getContentPane.add(label);
frame.pack;
screenSize = get(0,'ScreenSize'); 
frame.setSize(screenSize(3),screenSize(4));
frame.setLocation(0,0);
frame.show;

%what I need to make run but with the above definition it doesn't work
if mouse.getButton()
   [x,y]=mouse.getPoint();
end
```

I tried stupidly *ginput* but it creates another figure. This code shows correctly the full screen image but events about where I click, no. Matlab returns an error about *mouse=java.awt.event.MouseEvent;* definition. It reports: *Undefined variable "java" or class "java.awt.event".*
The problem is the imported java classes, and maybe how I used them. How could I solve? I find everywhere but I didn't find any practical solution. Could you suggest any other solution, also without using java?

Comment: What version numbers for Java and Matlab does `ver` return? Is this really the error message you get when you run the code above? I get a different one!

Comment: I get: `MATLAB Version: 8.6.0.26**** (R2015b)
MATLAB License Number: ********
Operating System: Microsoft Windows 8.1 Pro N Version 6.3 (Build 9600)
Java Version: Java 1.7.0_60-b19 with Oracle Corporation Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM mixed mode`

Comment: Then I am sure you don't get the error message you pasted with the code you pasted here!

Comment: I run my code: `frame = javax.swing.JFrame;

mouse=java.awt.event;

frame.setUndecorated(true);
icon = javax.swing.ImageIcon(jimg);
label = javax.swing.JLabel(icon);
frame.getContentPane.add(label);
frame.pack;
screenSize = get(0,'ScreenSize');  
frame.setSize(screenSize(3),screenSize(4));
frame.setLocation(0,0);
frame.show;

if mouse.getButton()
    [x,y]=mouse.getPoint();
end` and it returns: _Undefined variable "java" or class "java.awt.event".

Error in my_name-file (line 81)
mouse=java.awt.event;_ I don't understand

Comment: That's a different code and here the problem is clear. In Matlab you can only assign Objects to Variables, not packages. `java.awt.event` is a package.

Comment: I wrote I tried also  `mouse=java.awt.event` without success. But what is the correct object to assign to _mouse_?

Comment: No solution?? No one else could help? I think the solution is not to far from what I found. No other suggestions?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/103969/discussion-between-sps-and-daniel).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply I have to use the command:

```
[A]=get(0,'PointerLocation')
```

and in the matrix A I get the pointer position everywhere it is on screen, also on java frame image.

Comment: Now I have to get a mouse event. A guide to integrate C++ code in Matlab?